# Change the color of the axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Here's the relevant code:

```
ggplot.3plus<-ggplot(summary.3plus, aes(x=sp1, y=fract.mean, fill=ForestAge)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge())+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 1.175))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fract.mean-se, ymax=fract.mean+se),
                width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                position=position_dodge(.9))

ggplot.3plus<- ggplot.3plus + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

You can see that with the last line of code, I can change the color of the axis title, but not the color of the axis LABELS.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What about

```
ggplot.3plus + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(colour="red"))
```

See [ggplot2 wiki page](https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/New-theme-system) for more theme details.