# Colorize labels for a group of points

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Is it possible, in ggplot2, to colorize labels for a group of points?**

I would like to color some of the left-hand-side text labels in the plot below to show the swing states in red colour, in addition to the red marker shown in the plot itself:

[image: electoral dot plot]

[The code (with data) is here.](https://gist.github.com/4523631) -- **edited to reflect answer**

- I know [how to colour all labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399930/how-to-change-axis-label-color-in-ggplot2) ([here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568032/in-ggplot2-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-axis-labels)), but that's not what I need here.
- Ideally, I'd also like to improve the legend but am unsure exactly how.

The plot is far from perfect, so additional suggestions are very welcome. There are [far better graphs](http://jackman.stanford.edu/blog/?p=2620) out there if anyone's interested (but I'm not good enough to code them).

Comment: In your link for colouring labels, instead of just using "red" you could use a colour vector of blue and red etc , colouring the labels in the order they appear in your axis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [customize ggplot2 axis labels with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors)

Comment: @camille yes, it looks like the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Colors of labels (axis texts) are set by argument `element_text=` in function `theme()`. You can set different colors for each label. As there is a column `Swing` with levels, it can be used to set colors.

```
dw_plot + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = ifelse(dw_data$Swing=="Swing State","red","grey")))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. The [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/element_text.html) should mention that. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

The answers stated above work as of today; however, they throw warning which discourages from using the suggested method with `ifelse` inside `element_text()`. The reason why vectorisation in `element_text()` is not documented in `ggplot2` is because it is not supported feature (it works due to a chance). Please see the following [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3492) on GitHub where this specific problem was discussed.

The answers provided above will result in the following warning:

```
# Warning message:
# Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
# Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

The following code illustrates the point (using slightly updated example provided by SlowLearner - original data are not available) and shows my solution that supports the vectorisation using the [ggtext](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package and `element_markdown()`.

```
library(ggplot2); packageVersion("ggplot2")
# ‘3.3.0’
library(ggtext); packageVersion("ggtext") #; install.packages("ggtext") # https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext
# ‘0.1.0’

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(state = paste("State_", LETTERS, sep = ""), 
                margin = runif(26, -50, 50), 
                swing = rep(c("no", "yes", "no"), times = c(10, 6, 10)))

mycolours <- c("yes" = "red", "no" = "black")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = margin, y = state)) +
     geom_point(size = 5, aes(colour = swing)) +
     scale_color_manual("Swing", values = mycolours) +
     theme(
          # The following line uses vectorisation (such as rep or ifelse).
          # This is not officially supported. Works by a chance and gives impression of a feature.
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour = rep(c("black", "red", "black"), times = c(10, 6, 10)))
          )

# Throws the following warning:
# Warning message:
# Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
# Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2. 

# The following code uses ggtext method # element_markdown(),
# This is how this question should be solved because the vectorisation method may not work in the future inside element_text().
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = margin, y = state)) +
     geom_point(size = 5, aes(colour = swing)) +
     scale_color_manual("Swing", values = mycolours) +
     theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown(colour = rep(c("black", "red", "black"), times = c(10, 6, 10))))
# No warning occurs. This will also correctly calculate other aesthetic such as size.
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answer already accepted, but just as a visual example... For more complex schemes you can simply add a column to the data frame with the required colours and reference that instead of using 'red' and 'black' as per below.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
x <- data.frame(state = paste("State_", LETTERS, sep = ""), 
   margin = runif(26, -50, 50), swing = rep("no", 26))
x[c(10:15), 'swing'] <- "yes"
mycolours <- c("yes" = 'red', "no" = "black")

ggplot(data = x, aes(x = margin, y = state)) +
    geom_point(size = 5, aes(colour = swing)) +
    scale_color_manual("Swing", values = mycolours) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 
        ifelse(x$swing == 'yes', 'red', 'black'))) +
    theme()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your method might be simpler than my code, so thanks -- and thanks again for your comprehension at Cross Validated. My data, however, is a bit more complex because of the 2008/2012/swing three elements. I hope to simplify the code in the future.

Comment: @Fr. Yes, your data (and chart) is more complex while this is just a minimal reproducible example. I looked at your original code and it seemed serviceable so I assume you'll be able to patch things together.