# Coloring ggplot2 axis tick labels based on data displayed at axis tick positions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset:

```
top_bot_5_both <- structure(list(
  name = structure(c(20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 
                     11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), 
                   .Label = c("Michele Bachmann", "Donald Trump", "Ted Cruz", 
                              "Newt Gingrich", "Rick Santorum", "Terry McAuliffe", 
                              "Nancy Pelosi", "Debbie Wasserman Schultz", 
                              "Tammy Baldwin", "Joe Biden", "Rand Paul", "Jeb Bush", 
                              "John Kasich", "Barack Obama", "Bill Clinton", 
                              "Hillary Clinton", "Nathan Deal", "Tim Kaine", 
                              "Rob Portman", "Sherrod Brown"), 
                   class = "factor"),
  Party = c("Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", 
            "Democratic", "Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", 
            "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", 
            "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic"), 
  total_ratings = c(35L, 48L, 51L, 49L, 296L, 41L, 599L, 64L, 80L, 55L, 
                    61L, 472L, 123L, 82L, 61L, 31L, 35L, 48L, 33L, 75L), 
  sum = c(22, 29, 21, 18, 96, 12, 172, 16, 18, 2, -86, -525, -94, -57, 
          -42, -19, -14, -7, -4, -1), 
  score = c(0.628571428571429, 0.604166666666667, 0.411764705882353, 
            0.36734693877551, 0.324324324324324, 0.292682926829268, 
            0.287145242070117, 0.25, 0.225, 0.0363636363636364, -1.40983606557377, 
            -1.11228813559322, -0.764227642276423, -0.695121951219512, 
            -0.688524590163934, -0.612903225806452, -0.4, -0.145833333333333, 
            -0.121212121212121, -0.0133333333333333)), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -20L), 
  .Names = c("name", "Party", "total_ratings", "sum", "score"))
```

I want to make a column graph that has the y-axis text mirror the fill color in the graph itself. Following the suggestion from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors), I added the column `color` to my tibble

```
top_bot_5_both <- top_bot_5_both %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(Party == "Democratic", "#1A80C4", "#CC3D3D"))
```

And then graphed it as such:

```
ggplot(top_bot_5_both, aes(x = name, y = score, fill = Party)) +
  geom_col(size = 1, color = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10.5, size = 1.5, linetype = "twodash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Democratic" = "#1A80C4", "Republican" = "#CC3D3D")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = top_bot_5_both$color),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.position = "bottom", 
    legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

In the graph, the `fill` correctly identifies each politician's party but the `axis.text.y` does not. For instance, Michelle Bachmann is a Republican, so her column should have red fill (which it does) and should have red axis text (which it does not).

I then decided to wrap it in `rev()` by using `axis.text.y = element_text(color = rev(top_bot_5_both$color)` which created this graph, which is *closer* to correct.

```
ggplot(top_bot_5_both, aes(x = name, y = score, fill = Party)) +
  geom_col(size = 1, color = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10.5, size = 1.5, linetype = "twodash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Democratic" = "#1A80C4", "Republican" = "#CC3D3D")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = rev(top_bot_5_both$color)),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.position = "bottom", 
    legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

The `top_bot_5_both$color` vector is in the correct order in the tibble, but it somehow gets messed up during the actual graphing. Maybe it has to do with `top_bot_5_both$name` being a factor, but that is necessary I believe in order to graph the scores in descending order.

Other things I tried that did not work:

- Getting rid of `coord_flip()` and changing y to x, etc.
- Not generating the column `top_bot_5_both$color` and instead putting the `ifelse(...)` command inside `element_text(color = ...)`
- And I can't do this manually because I plan to repeat this analysis in the future and the politicians' order on the y-axis will likely change

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in here somewhere?

Comment: A suggestion - minimise your question to the core component and provide a reproducible example, preferably with an inbuild or self-generated dataset. There's a lot in here.  Suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is reproducible, though, so I think it's fine. The solution is fairly straightforward also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's important to realize that when you're writing `axis.text.y = element_text(color = ...)`, you're not mapping data to colors using the regular ggplot2 mapping mechanism, you're manually assigning colors to specific axis labels. Therefore, the colors you assign need to be exactly in the right order.

When you inspect your data frame, you can see that the rows are not in the order in which they are plotted; the order is set by the levels of the `name` factor. Therefore, you have to use that order for your colors as well. You can do that using the `order()` function:

```
colors <- top_bot_5_both$color[order(top_bot_5_both$name)]
```

Now, with this color vector, we can make the plot as intended:

```
ggplot(top_bot_5_both, aes(x = name, y = score, fill = Party)) +
  geom_col(size = 1, color = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 10.5, size = 1.5, linetype = "twodash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Democratic" = "#1A80C4", "Republican" = "#CC3D3D")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = colors),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm, and thank you for the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. One issue that doesn't directly pertain to your question: The colors look darker in the bars than in the text. I would try using somewhat darker colors for the text or lighter colors for the bars, and/or remove the thick black lines around the bars.