# How to customize ggplot2 axis labels with different colors when values are continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

The post [customize ggplot2 axis labels with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors/51794122#51794122) describes how you can change the colors of each label when each (discrete) value in your data source has got its own corresponding label. But how do you efficiently reference and format each label when you have a larger dataset and each value in that dataset is not represented by its own value (which quickly becomes the case for continuous values)?

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to reference all Y values (like 1.22, 0.5, -1.1 etc.) and assign a unique colour to them?

Comment: Just the labels assigned to the y-axis [-2, -1, 0, 1]

Comment: What about manually defining the Y-axis labels as `labels <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1)` and then using `cols <- ifelse(labels < 0, "red", ifelse(labels == 0, "black", "blue"))`?

Comment: Cool! Please consider writing it up as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work for ggplot2 3.0.0. For earlier versions of ggplot2, the exact structure of `ggplot_build(plt1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.label` will vary.

---

In the reproducible dataset and corresponding chart below, you'll se that both columns A and B in the dataframe df have 10 observations, and that B displayed on the y-axis is assigned with 4 labels. Using the `ggplot_build()` and `theme()` you can reference and format the y labels any way you like. Below, negative and positive numbers are assigned the colors red and blue, respectively. Zero remains black.

**Snippet**

```
# settings
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

# data
A = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
B = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
df <- data.frame(A,B)

# initial plot
plt1 <- ggplot(data = df) + aes(x=A, y=B)+geom_line()

# retrieve lables using ggplot_build()
yLabVals <- as.numeric(ggplot_build(plt1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels)

# create color list
yLabs <- ifelse(yLabVals < 0, "red", "blue")
yLabs[yLabVals == 0] <- 'black'

# plot
plt2 <- plt1 + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, colour = yLabs))
plt2
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: ggplot2 >= 3.3.0 has broken this solution.  The scales use proto now: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#rewrite-of-axis-code

Answer (score 1):

For ggplot2 >= 3.3.0, the scales use proto now.  Here's a new hack that seems to work. This whole approach remains very fragile, and ggplot throws a warning about supplying a vector to `element_text`.  It would be worth finding a more robust solution.

```
# settings
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

# data
A = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
B = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
df <- data.frame(A,B)

# initial plot
plt1 <- ggplot(data = df) + aes(x=A, y=B)+geom_line()

# retrieve lables using ggplot_build()
yLabVals <- as.numeric(ggplot_build(plt1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$get_labels())    
# create color list
yLabs <- ifelse(yLabVals < 0, "red", "blue")
yLabs[yLabVals == 0] <- 'black'

# plot
plt2 <- plt1 + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, colour = yLabs))
plt2
```

[image: ggplot output]

Comment: Tried this with `facet_wrap`, and it looks like it has to be the same colour scheme across all facets

Answer (score 0):

Selectively colouring axis text can be done more idiomatically using `labels` in `scale_y_continuous` paired with `ggtext::element_markdown()`.

`scale_y_continuous` takes a parameter `labels` which can be a function. This function maps a break value to the text that is displayed on the plot.

Use the `ggtext` package to interpret the y axis text as markdown.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = \(break_value) {
      dplyr::case_when(
        break_value %in% c(-1, -2) ~ paste0("<span style = 'color:red'>", break_value, "</span>"),
        break_value == 1 ~ paste0("<span style = 'color:blue'>", break_value, "</span>"),
        TRUE ~ as.character(break_value)
      )
    }
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )
```

[image: Selectively Coloured Axis Text]