# Customize ggplot2 axis labels with specific colours

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to customize the axis labels such that the line color of the plot and the x value have the same color. For example, I would like to color time steps 08:00, 15:00, and 18:30 with "#FF9999" and 07:00,15:30,19:00,21:00 with "0000FF".

[image]

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", 
"05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", 
"07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", 
"08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", 
"10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", 
"12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", 
"14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", 
"15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", 
"17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", 
"19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", 
"21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", 
"22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45", "00:00", "00:15", 
"00:30", "00:45", "01:00", "01:15", "01:30", "01:45", "02:00", 
"02:15", "02:30", "02:45", "03:00", "03:15", "03:30", "03:45"
), index = 1:96, variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "value", class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0.00120336943441637, 0.00401123144805455, 0.00481347773766546, 
    0.0116325711993582, 0.0104292017649418, 0.0236662655435219, 
    0.0284797432811873, 0.0709987966305656, 0.0770156438026474, 
    0.0882470918572002, 0.0918572001604493, 0.201363818692339, 
    0.219013237063779, 0.281989570798235, 0.298435619735259, 
    0.503409546730846, 0.555956678700361, 0.67428800641797, 0.707180104292018, 
    0.8896911351785, 0.922583233052547, 0.935018050541516, 0.936221419975933, 
    0.963096670677898, 0.974729241877256, 0.985960689931809, 
    0.984757320497393, 0.984757320497393, 0.994785399117529, 
    1, 0.997994384275973, 0.919775371038909, 0.902527075812274, 
    0.860409145607702, 0.854793421580425, 0.756117127958283, 
    0.768953068592058, 0.837545126353791, 0.847172081829122, 
    0.944243882872042, 0.963497793822704, 0.965503409546731, 
    0.967107902125953, 0.957079823505816, 0.969915764139591, 
    0.9558764540714, 0.953469715202567, 0.890894504612916, 0.882872041716807, 
    0.8235058162856, 0.805054151624549, 0.661452065784196, 0.631768953068592, 
    0.549538708383474, 0.51544324107501, 0.300842358604091, 0.277978339350181, 
    0.235058162855997, 0.214199759326113, 0.143602085840353, 
    0.139590854392298, 0.129161652627357, 0.127557160048135, 
    0.0946650621740874, 0.0934616927396711, 0.0886482150020056, 
    0.0834336141195347, 0.0709987966305656, 0.0722021660649819, 
    0.0705976734857601, 0.0701965503409547, 0.0605695948656237, 
    0.0605695948656237, 0.0573606097071801, 0.0561572402727637, 
    0.0389089450461292, 0.036101083032491, 0.0344965904532692, 
    0.0348977135980746, 0.0260730044123546, 0.0280786201363819, 
    0.0260730044123546, 0.0260730044123546, 0.0212595266746891, 
    0.0208584035298837, 0.0164460489370237, 0.0156438026474128, 
    0.00922583233052547, 0.00882470918572002, 0.00842358604091456, 
    0.00882470918572002, 0.00240673886883273, 0.00200561572402728, 
    0.00200561572402728, 0.00200561572402728)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-96L))
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862452/6851825

Comment: Note that going along Jon's answer does return a "warning": `Warning message:
Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.`. It does work however. But note it is unaware of any names, so you need prior knowledge of your axis'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to my own and Jon's comment you could add something like

```
f <- function(x){
  d <- rep('black', NROW(x))
  one <- which(x %in% c("08:00", "15:00", "18:30"))
  two <- which(x %in% c("07:00", "15:30", "19:00", "21:00"))
  d[one] <- '#FF9999'
  d[two] <- '#0000FF'
  d
}
colour <- f(df$time)

plot + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = colour,
                                   angle = 90))
```

Note that you will get a warning

> Warning message:
> Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
> Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

But it does work. It is however not aware of the tick labels themselves. By this I mean it will colour based on **position** in `colour` compared to the position on the axis. So You'll need to match the position somehow (I might have "misaligned" the colours in my example)