# Ggplot2 vary x axis label colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have (x,y) data where x = months(Jan 2020-March 2021) and y = values,

I am plotting all of these on the same graph, just by there months, I would like to distingush between the years by changing the color of the x label months (jan 2020- dec 2020) to be the color blue and the data labeled Jan 2021 - March 2021 to be labeled green.

I would also like to have a legend that shows the year 2020 is blue on the x axis and 2021 is green.

example of data would be :

data:

```
dates = seq.Date(from =as.Date("01/01/2020", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                 to=as.Date("01/03/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"), by="month")

y = c(1:1:15)
df = data.frame(dates,y)
```

when plotting, would like x axis label `df$dates[1:12]` to be the color blue and `df$dates[13:15]` to be color green

Comment: It might be useful to add some dummy examples of the kind of data you are working with

Comment: @GiulioCentorame see edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [customize ggplot2 axis labels with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `ggtext` package which allows for styling of labels and theme elements via markdown or HTML.

As you offered no information about the type of chart you are trying to achieve I went for a bar chart:

```r
dates = seq.Date(from =as.Date("01/01/2020", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                 to=as.Date("01/03/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"), by="month")

y = c(1:1:15)
df = data.frame(dates,y)

mylabs <- function(x) {
  cols <- ifelse(lubridate::year(x) == 2020, "blue", "green")
  glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {cols}'>{format(x, '%b %Y')}</span>")
}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(df, aes(dates, y, fill = lubridate::year(dates) == 2020)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
               labels = mylabs, 
               guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2),
               expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "grey", "FALSE" = "grey"),
                    labels = c("TRUE" = 2020, "FALSE" = 2021)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown()) +
  labs(fill = NULL, x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("blue", "green"))))
```

[image]