# how to add colored tick label to ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I am new to R and recently generate this bubble heatmap using ggplot2. I would like to add colored ticks to top of my figure. I have 7 different colors on the x axis and would like to add a set of colored squares matching to the text, to top of the chart and underneath the label.
Thank you and appreciated any help.
Please see the link for the data.
[Text](https://stackoverflow.com)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13mPQaCmhb6pABQ102srafQPryc6r8hNg/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(reshape2)
bb<-c(1, 1.3, 3)
labels<-c("0.1","0.05", "0.001")
x<-c("Blue", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Brown", "Pink", "Red", "Grey")
 ggplot(df, aes(x= Var2, y = Var1))+
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color = "gray")+
  geom_point(aes(color = cor, size = log.P))+
  labs(color="Correlation")+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,12), name = "P value",
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "grey")), breaks=bb, labels=labels)+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits=x)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = cor), color = "black", size = 4, vjust=2.5)+
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", mid="white", high = "red")+theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, angle = 40, hjust=0.1, vjust = 0.1, color=x),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.title=element_text(size=15),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.7,"cm"))
```

[image]

(there are 7 different color modules on x axis)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/38862303/7941188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to add some colored squares beneath your colored labels would be via an additional `geom_text` layer. As the `label` I use a filled square with UTF-8 code `"\u25A0"`.

Using some fake random data to mimic your real data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(color = cor, size = log.P)) +
  labs(color = "Correlation") +
  scale_size_continuous(
    range = c(1, 12), name = "P value",
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "grey")), breaks = bb, labels = labels
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits = x) +
  geom_text(aes(label = cor), color = "black", size = 4, vjust = 2.5) +
  # Add square ticks
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = x, y = 7.5), aes(x = x, y = y), color = x, label = "\u25A0", size = 6, vjust = 0) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, angle = 40, hjust = 0.1, vjust = 0.1, color = x),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.7, "cm"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

x <- c("Blue", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Brown", "Pink", "Red", "Grey")

df <- data.frame(
  Var2 = rep(x, 7),
  Var1 = rep(1:7, each = 7),
  cor = round(runif(49, -1, 1), 2),
  log.P = runif(49, 0, 10)
)
```