# How can I set the x-axis label of the error bar not to overlap in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-mining, axis-labels

How do I set each category of values on the x-axis not to overlap?(cen-con-lib)

Also, I want to change the color of each category (e.g., assigning con to red) How can I change it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIP7M.png)
`

```
## Visualization
STM_estimate %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=covariate.value, y=estimate, color= covariate.value))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci.lower, ymax=ci.upper),width = .2)+ #error bar-geom_errorbar
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_fivethirtyeight()+
  facet_grid(~topic)
```

`

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!! Thanks to you, I changed the angle of the x-axis label so that the x-axis does not overlap now.
Could you give me some advice again on changing the color of the x-axis label?

Comment: And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors). I haven't answered because there is no data.